# Docker network interfaces card bandwidth limitation?

Tags: docker, docker-network

How docker’s network interface bandwidth limitation is determine? is it based on the physical network card bandwidth? and if not, from where is taken the bandwidth?

I have a certain application deployment where docker creates multiple nics. Now, when we send data to this node, we send it to the physical NIC, which is 1Gbps, we are able to see incoming data in the physical nic and, as we are expecting we also see data on the nics created by docker, now when I want to determine the bandwidth usage per second for that node, can I assume that the bandwidth used by all the docker nics is it taken from the physical bandwidth?
For example: in a run test, if the physical nic bandwidth usage was 100Mbps and the total of 4 docker nics was 200Mbps, then could we say the physical nic total bandwidth usage was 400Mbps?

Answer (score 0):

Docker don't handle such feature. See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9607

Have a look at cgroup net_cls https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I need to know is if when I see network traffic in the docker network cards the bandwidth used by those docker nics is part of the available bandwidth from the physical NIC.